# How can I catch onload event when using jquery mobile dialog?

Tags: jquery-mobile, dialog, onload

When it's a normal jquery mobile page, I can use the following code as onload function:

```
$(document).delegate("#page", "pageinit", function(){});
```

However, it's not working when a page is opened as dialog(using ).
How can I catch onload event?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends a lot on how your page is structured. First of all your delegate call is targeting a specific id `#page` so if your dialog isn't using that id, then it won't be handled. You can use a more generic selector like this:

`$(document).delegate('div[data-role=dialog]', 'pageinit', function() {})`

I created an example that shows how to capture pageinit and pageshow for normal pages and dialogs http://jsfiddle.net/kiliman/hQh6u/1/